# Can I colocate pytest tests in the module under test?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

Pytest is so handy and useful that I find myself wanting to use it when developing even very simple scripts. But since they are very simple scripts I like to keep the tests in the same module as the functions being tested.
Since the module under test is not named with pattern matching the defaults (test*, *test, etc) I run the tests like this:

```
> pytest mymodule.py
```

The test functions *do* follow the default pattern and are found/collected by pytest and failing assertions are reported.

The problem is that I can't get assertion introspection to work with python2.7. The same scenario *does* give me assertion introspection using python 3.7.

If I put tests in a separate test_module.py then assertion introspection works again.

I suspect this has something to do with the import mechanism pytest uses while doing test discovery but I can't figure it out.

#### Update:

The difference in behavior between py2 and py3 was actually a difference in the pytest version (4.6.x vs 6.0.x). It is still unclear why 4.6 doesn't do some sort of assertion introspection on tests declared inside non-test modules when that module is explicitly tested with `pytest mymodule.py`. Maybe this was added as a feature after 4.6 but I can't find mention in changelog.

Assertion introspection on "non-test" modules can be achieved with either of two workarounds.

1. Add the script module in a pytest.ini setting like so...

```
[pytest]
python_files = mymodule.py
```

2. Register the module for rewrite using

```
pytest.register_assert_rewrite('mymodule')
```

in a conftest.py file or the **init**.py of your package.

Comment: You can try to add your test files in `pytest.ini` (`python_files = test_*.py mymodule.py ...`) to add them the search pattern, though I'm not sure if that changes the behavior under Python 2.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yes that works with py2! Now consistent behavior with py3. But seems weird that was inconsistent in the first place.

Comment: pytest 4.x is the last one ([currently 4.6.11](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/4.6.11/#files)) which is Python 2.7 (and 3) compatible. v5.x is Py3 only, and their features/test discovery would differ. So, when you're running the Py3 version, which pytest release are you on?

Comment: @aneroid Ahh, ok that's a good point. py27: pytest 4.6.11, py3: pytest 6.0.0rc1. For some reason I thought I'd checked that already but now I can read the docs and compare.

Comment: Just verified same behavior using 4.6.11 from py3.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen You can also pytest.register_assert_rewrite('mymodule') in a conftest.py. Not sure what the implications of doing it each way are.